# OpenVPN only connects when am root

Tags: release-juno, vpn, openvpn

Is it normal that you have to be a root user to connect to OpenVPN client because when I am not a root user this message appears and it fails to connect:

`Tue Dec 11 03:04:31 2018 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1) Tue Dec 11 03:04:31 2018 Exiting due to fatal error`

But when I am a root user it connects just fine. And is it safe to connect to a VPN client with root privileges?

I don't know if this is normal or not. Pardon me for my ignorance on this subject matter.

Regards, pole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVPN tries to creates TUN/TAPdevices as needed, and only the root user can do this

You could use `sudo` to run it by editing the `sudoers` file, to allow an usergroup like `vpnusers` to start OpenVPN without password

You can add the following line to the file

```
%vpnusers ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/openvpn /path/to/openvpn.conf
```

---

I recommend you better to follow the instructions from the OpenVPN wiki, it shows you how you could run it as an user

> By default, OpenVPN runs as the root user. This page seeks to describe how to instead run as an unprivileged user, "openvpn", instead. This is more secure than the built-in directives(--user and --group) because the openvpn process is never started with root permissions. Additionally, reconnects(including those which push fresh routes and configuration changes) which normally break after privileges are dropped via --user are handled without issue.

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/UnprivilegedUser